# Sort data frame in r on two conditions with both increasing and decreasing columns

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe

I have data that looks like this in `df_Filtered` (where filtered stands for a df for a specific country):

```
Year Region    Percentage_of_national_sell
2012 Berlin    84%
2010 Hamburg   101%
2011 Stettin   98%
2012 Stettin   100%
2012 Hamburg   122%
2011 Berlin    111%
2010 Berlin    101%
2010 Stettin   87%
2011 Hamburg   58%
```

What I want to do is to sort `df_Filtered` so that I first get it sorted by `Region` and then by `Year` (starting with `Berlin` and then get `2010`, `2011`, `2012` in that specific order). Both `Region` and `Year` should be increasing.

I tried: `df_Filtered[ order(df_Filtered$Region, (df_Filtered$Year)) , ]` which works when I get the output in text in Rstudio, but it does not seem to change the order of the data frame when I try to remap it:

```
df_Filtered <- df_Filtered[ order(df_Filtered$Region, (df_Filtered$Year)) , ]
```

Is there any way to change the order of the rows in the data frame itself? I want to later export it to LaTex to make nice tables, that is why the order is important.

Comment: Obviously a duplicate... 
    data<-data[order(data$Region,-data$Year),]
    data<-data[order(data$Region,data$Year),]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `sqldf`:

**Your sample data:**

```
df=read.table(text="Year Region    Percentage_of_national_sell
          2012 Berlin    84%
          2010 Hamburg   101%
          2011 Stettin   98%
          2012 Stettin   100%
          2012 Hamburg   122%
          2011 Berlin    111%
          2010 Berlin    101%
          2010 Stettin   87%
          2011 Hamburg   58%",header=T)
```

**Code:**

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select * from df order by Region, Year")
```

**OR** (Base R solution)

```
df[order(df$Region,df$Year),]
```

**Output:**

```
Year  Region Percentage_of_national_sell
1 2010  Berlin                        101%
2 2011  Berlin                        111%
3 2012  Berlin                         84%
4 2010 Hamburg                        101%
5 2011 Hamburg                         58%
6 2012 Hamburg                        122%
7 2010 Stettin                         87%
8 2011 Stettin                         98%
9 2012 Stettin                        100%
```

Comment: @KGB91: Does it satisfy your requirement?

Comment: Thanks! But I want to start with `2010` in `year`. (I might have been unclear here) And it should mainly be sorted on the region, not the year.

Comment: The edited code works fine! Thanks a lot! That is SQL-code, right?

Comment: @KGB91: I have updated the answer. First, you mentioned Region should be increasing and Year decreasing in the question so I did as per the question.

Comment: @KGB91: Yes this is a `sqldf` (For R) which is similar to `sql`.

Comment: I am new to R, but that seems handy. And yeah, I made a mistake in my post.

Answer (score 1):

The `dplyr` package works also nice for this:  (data is not complete)

```
library(dplyr)

Region <- c("Ham", "Ste", "Ste", "Ham", "Ber", "Ber")
Year <- c(2012, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2012, 2011)
Percentage <- c(101, 98, 100, 122, 111, 101)
df <- data.frame(Region, Year, Percentage)

df %>% arrange(Region, Year)
```

Output:

```
  Year Region Percentage
1 2011    Ber        101
2 2012    Ber        111
3 2012    Ham        101
4 2012    Ham        122
5 2010    Ste         98
6 2011    Ste        100
```